# Bootstrap-Vue b-tab: CSS does not seem to be applying to active-nav-item-class

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am experimenting with tabs in Bootstrap-Vue.  I am trying to adjust the styling on an active tab.  From the documentation at https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/tabs#active-classes, I've seen this example that changes the active tab styling.  I understand that I am to modify the active-nav-item-class attribute, like so:

```
<b-tabs
    active-nav-item-class="font-weight-bold text-success"
    active-tab-class="font-weight-bold text-success"
    content-class="mt-3"
>
```

In my JSFiddle which you can see at https://jsfiddle.net/b4o1kL2f/1/, I am similarly trying to set the active-nav-item-class to a class style in CSS, by binding it with Vue:

```
<b-tabs  pills vertical :active-nav-item-class="'tab-active-class'">
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.tab-active-class {
  background-color: red;
}
```

But it seems like the active tab background color is not changing. Can anyone spot what I might be doing wrong? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class is applying to the HTML element but the problem is that `.nav-link.active` has specificity more than `.tab-active-class`, So you have to increase the specificity of `.tab-active-class`

```
.nav-link.active.tab-active-class {
  background-color: red;
}
```

or

```
.tab-active-class {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much!!  I really appreciate it!